# Rubymine for remote SDK. Gems downloading and suddenly stop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ssh

I'm having this issue since yesterday and I am not sure what could be the problem. I have a Rails application that I want to run against a remote SDK installed on my VirtualBox (Ubuntu); yesterday I was able to set it up on another VM I have and when I went to Settings in Rubymine and added the SSH credentials, it took some time but finally a lot of gems were downloaded and I was able to run the project directly from Rubymine environment, trying to prepare everything for debug.

I had to change my VirtualBox and now when I connect to it via SSH it starts "Collecting files..." for a while and then "Downloading..." the gems... it looks like it restarts for a couple of times and then at some point, after a while and without any further notice, it stops.

If it helps, my host is Windows 7, my guest is Ubuntu 14.04; my RVM is 1.9.3-p392.

Any ideas? I'm surprised because this worked like a charm yesterday and today is not. Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

What version is your Rubymine? I had issue back with version 6.x with remote rubies freezing the system. Also are you using a Vagrant box? I have seen some of the Vagrant boxes have issues as well. I would log in to the Ubuntu Guest via command line/SSH and see if you still have issues downloading gems.